# how do I save string without some of its characters?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a programm which gives out the input string without its vowels.but it only gives the first charachter of the string .here is the code:

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main(){

    char ch;
    while(cin.get(ch)){
        cout<<ch;
        char a=cin.peek();
        while( a==65 || a==69 || a==73 || a==79 || a==85 || a==97 || a==101 || a==105 || a==111 || a==117)
            cin.ignore(1 , a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no string in this code. `char` is a type which holds a single character. Look up `std::string` and how to use it.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Your question mentions strings, but has no string or char array in the code. It doesn't try to store any characters or display anything. Are you looking for a solution where each character is checked as it's input or would it be ok if an entire string was input and afterwards had the vowels removed?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use hard-coded guesses at character codes. That `while` statement should be `while (a == 'a' || a == 'e'` etc., if I'm guessing correctly at what those codes are supposed to mean. Or, even better, `"const char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU"; while (std::find(std::begin(vowels), std::end(vowels), ch))`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve a problem like this, start by breaking the problem into smaller parts.  A possible decomposition is:

1. Are there characters still to read from the input?  No: Great, we are done!
2. Read in a character
3. Is the character a vowel? Yes: Goto 1.
4. Output the character
5. Goto 1.

Then in code, you can translate this into:

```
// 1) Are there characters still to read?
while (std::cin.good())
{
    // 2) Read in a character
    char ch;
    std::cin.get(ch);

    // 3) Is the character a vowel?
    //     For the test for a vowel, you can use something similar to
    //     what you have at the moment, or better still: consider
    //     writing a function like isVowel in @Shreevardhan answer.
    if ( /* TODO: Test if the character is a vowel... */)
    {
        // Skip the rest of the loop and go back to 1
        continue;
    }

    // 4) Output the good character
    std::cout << ch;

    // 5) Reached the end of the loop, so goto 1
}
```

It's a good habit to break your problem down into smaller parts.  I often start a new project by first writing out a list/comments (or even drawing a flow diagram) to break up the problem into more manageable pieces.

Comment: Good approach. But sometimes it's better to invert the logic. Instead of checking whether the character is a vowel, check whether it's not, and if that's the case, write it out. The code becomes much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isVowel(char c) {
    c = tolower(c);
    return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u';
}

int main() {
    char c;
    while (cin.get(c))
        if (!isVowel(c))
            cout << c;
    return 0;
}
```

Add your storing logic inside.

A more C++-ish code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) {
        c = tolower(c);
        return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u';
    }), s.end());
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

See a [demo](http://ideone.com/iVrzSu).

Answer (score 0):

Other answers show how to solve this problem in a more intuitive manner.
Anyway, when looking at your code consider the following:

```
while( a==65 || a==69 || a==73 || a==79 || a==85 || a==97 || a==101 || a==105 || a==111 || a==117)
            cin.ignore(1 , a);
```

As you do a while loop with conditions around the value of `a`, and as `cin.ignore(1 , a)` does not change the value of `a`, you wont ever leave this loop unless an exception is thrown, right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use the boost library.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
boost::erase_all(str, "a");
```